# Understanding `bracket` Function

Tags: haskell

Looking at the `bracket` function from [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch08.html#sec_exceptions):

```
bracket :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
bracket before after during = do
  a <- before
  c <- during a `onException` after a
  after a
  return c
```

In the event of an exception, why does the `after` function only get called once? In other words, I'm confused at the apparent execution of `after a` twice in the event of an exception.

But, the code shows that `after a` only gets called, as I understand, once:

```
λ: >data MyException = MyException deriving Show
λ: >instance Exception MyException

λ: >let e = return MyException :: IO MyException

λ: >bracket e (const $ putStrLn "clean up!") return
clean up!
MyException
```

Comment: My guess would be that `onException` will execute `after a`, but then "re-raises" the exception, preventing the remaining of the function to be done, but I have not verified this. Like Python has an `try-exception` block but with `except: print(foo); raise` to reraise the exception after doing some instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs for `bracket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket):

> When you want to acquire a resource, do some work with it, and then release the resource, it is a good idea to use `bracket`, because `bracket` will install the necessary exception handler to release the resource in the event that an exception is raised during the computation. **If an exception is raised, then `bracket` will re-raise the exception (after performing the release).**

And [`onException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:onException):

> Like `finally`, but only performs the final action if there was an exception raised by the computation.

So if there is an exception thrown from `during a`, the first call to `after a` is executed, then the exception is rethrown, skipping the second `after a`; if there is no exception, only the second is executed.

Note that in your sample code, you’re *returning* an exception, not *throwing* it—to throw, you need to use `throw` or preferably `throwIO :: Exception e => e -> IO a`.